# Create an oracle pl/sql package using a package on a different remote database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to create a package or replace an existing package in a local database using a package from a different database without having to export it from the remote database?

Basically i have two environments/servers (DEV and QA).

The developers that work on the packages use the development environment and i would like to update the same packages in the QA environment using the package in DEV (ignore any possible issues for now e.g compilation failures etc).

Is it possible to frequently update the package in QA using the package in Dev as the source (instead of compiling from an .sql file)? Maybe a database link?

Comment: Are you planning to use the similar procedure when deploying to production (i.e. copy stuff from QA to PROD) ? If not how do you know your PROD will have the same code you've verified in QA ?

Comment: Yes but the only difference is that from QA to Prod the procedures are exported manually (for now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you could created a process on your target system which uses the DBMS_METADATA package on the remote system to fetch the DDL for the desired package spec and body, and then use dynamic SQL on local system to compile the fetched code.

Alternatively, you could use tools such as Oracle's SQL Developer for migrating code.  Using either the database diff functionality to detect differences and prepare the appropriate DDL scripts, or the Cart functionality to pick and choose what get's migrated.  However, I'm not sure how well the SQL Developer method can be automated.